# How to convert the time format in android?

Tags: java, android

I have the json response like this:

```
{
    "Modification": [
        {
            "lastModifiedTime": "1354024211735"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to convert the **lastModifiedTime** like this **10 Dec 2012 18:41** *(DD/MM/Year time)*. How I  will to achieve this output in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `SimpleDateFormat` :

```
 SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"); 
 Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(jsonObject.getString("lastModifiedTime"));
```

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"); ` This one.

Comment: Thank you Nunu. I got the output :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(json.getString("lastModifiedTime"));
return new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm").format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SimpleDateFormat`, from `Java`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US);
String date1 = format.format(new Date(1354024211735l));
```

Output: **27 Nov 2012 15:50**

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
String date2 = dateFormat.format(new Date(1354024211735l));
```

Output: **Nov 27, 2012 3:50:11 PM**

Answer (score 0):

Try something linke this

```
public class Test {

/**
 * Main Method
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDate(82233213123L, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));
}


/**
 * Return date in specified format.
 * @param milliSeconds Date in milliseconds
 * @param dateFormat Date format 
 * @return String representing date in specified format
 */
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
{
    // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

    // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date. 
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
     return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
}
```

Hope this helps